# "Fatal error in launcher: unable to create process with c:\pythonXX\python.exe" when launching jupyter after python re-install

Tags: python, jupyter, fatal-error

I had by error installed python twice (3.8 via Windows Store and 3.9 via python installer) on a Win10 machine and after removing both of them and reinstalling 3.9,  Python works fine but jupyter (installed with pip)  keeps returning the fatal error: Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"c:\pythonXX\python.exe"  "C:\Users\xx\AppData\Roaming\Python\PythonXX\Scripts\jupyter.exe" ': Le fichier spÚcifiÚ est introuvable.
(specified file not found in french)

I tried to specify the path to the python.exe in the kernel.json but no luck.

The folder c:\pythonXX\ doesn't exist, but I check the PATH and there's no mention of  this folder.

Does someone have an idea of how to correct it ? Or should I make a clean and full uninstall of Python again ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

After some searching on the jupyter/notebook github issues,  I found a correction/workaround:in my PATH environment variable, I had duplicate folders pointing to PythonXX and PythonXX/Scripts folders.
I kept the set corresponding to "where python" was, and forced the re-install of jupyter.

```
pip install jupyter --force-reinstall
```

and I was then able to launch jupyter without the error.